# How to use select a greater order when datetime is the same?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_A
(
    number_id int, 
    country varchar(50), 
    status varchar(50), 
    datetime date
);

INSERT INTO TBL_A
VALUES (121144, 'USA', 'CLICKED', '2021-10-09'),
       (121144, 'USA', 'CLAIMED', '2021-10-10'),
       (121144, 'USA', 'BOUGHT', '2021-10-11'),
       (121111, 'CAD', 'CLICKED', '2021-10-12'),
       (121111, 'CAD', 'CLAIMED', '2021-10-12'),
       (121111, 'CAD', 'BOUGHT', '2021-10-12'),
       (121133, 'AUS', 'CLICKED', '2021-10-14'),
       (121133, 'AUS', 'CLAIMED', '2021-10-14');
```

Based on the number_id and country, I want to grab the last status based on the datetime. The problem I am having is when the datetime has the same value. When this happens, I want the last status to follow this order:

```
> BOUGHT > CLAIMED > CLICKED
```

So if bought, claimed, and clicked have the same datetime, it should select BOUGHT. If there is no bought and claimed and clicked, have the datetime it should select CLAIMED.

I have this query to select the LAST status, but I need it to take into account the order when the datetime is the same:

```
SELECT    
    NUMBER_ID,
    COUNTRY,
    (array_agg(STATUS) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DATETIME DESC)[0])::varchar AS LAST_STATUS
FROM
    TBL_A
GROUP BY 
    1, 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DECODE` to add additiona column sort in case of a tie:

```
SELECT NUMBER_ID, COUNTRY
    ,(array_agg(STATUS) within group(order by DATETIME desc, 
                        DECODE(status, 'BOUGHT',1,'CLAIMED',2,'CLICKED',3, 99)
     )[0])::varchar as LAST_STATUS
from TBL_A
GROUP BY NUMBER_ID, COUNTRY;
```

Comment: this worked!! thank you :)